# Plural or singular after the word shedloads?

Tags: word-usage

I can see that we can say 'I have shed-loads of emails to check.'

Also I can see that we can say 'I have shed-loads of work to do.'

My question is, can we say 'I have shed-loads of works to do?' Any grammatical mistakes here?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! **work** is normally an uncount noun. You don't use uncount nouns in the plural. http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/nouns/uncount-nouns

Comment: "Works" is commonly used in the plural in phrases such as "brick works" and "steel works", where works refers to a factory complex. It is also used in such phrases as "works of art". But none of these phrases is used to describe work that awaits you. For this purpose you might say "I have shed-loads of tasks (or chores) to do", as an alternative.

Comment: It depends if you are using 'work' as a count noun or mass noun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to think about this is that "work" is like "water".  We can drink a lot of water, but we don't count it.  "Work" is that way too.  So, we can do shed-loads of jobs, or projects, but we do shed-loads of work.